# 'Package "drupal/core" is not installed' error even with local drush install

Tags: windows, drupal, drush

Apols, first time posting, not sure of protocol.
I have similar problem to [Package "drupal/core" is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76584573/) Trying to install Drush.
WAMP, PHP8, Windows 11

I have PATH to..\htdocs\drupal_test3\vendor\drush\drush in User variables in Environment variables
I have installed composer in ../htdocs/drupal_test3

```
./htdocs/drupal_test3
composer --version
Composer version 2.5.8 2023-06-09 17:13:21*
```

I cd to ../htdocs/drupal_test3/vendor/drush/drush
Type drush. I get

```
../htdocs/drupal_test3/vendor/drush/drush
$ drush --version
 [preflight] Package "drupal/core" is not installed
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: WAMP is yesteryear's technology. Use DDEV or Lando. Nevertheless, what happens when you `cd ../htdocs/drupal_test3 && ./vendor/drush/drush/drush --version`?

Comment: I think it should be 3 times `drush/`. Can also help you post your composer.json.

Comment: That is what I tried - cd to drush/drush and then drush --version. Tried your syntax, same result.
composer.json shows:
{
    "require": {
        "drush/drush": "^12.1"
    }
}

Comment: Spent a couple of days on this, to no avail, so I started over completely from scratch, installed Lando and worked forward from there. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. composer remove drush/drush
2. composer require drush/drush:^11

The above steps working fine for me

Comment: Still the same error message for me, I'm afraid.
composer.json now shows 
{
    "require": {
        "drush/drush": "^11"
    }
}

Comment: Have you installed drush globally ? ./vendor/bin/drush working for you could you please check it.

Comment: At the windows cmd prompt:
.\vendor\drush\drush>drush --version
gives the error:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\RuntimeException: Cannot find the home directory path: Your environment or operating system isn't supported. in .\vendor\symfony\filesystem\Path.php:204
Stack trace:
#0 .\vendor\drush\drush\drush.php(69): Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Path::getHomeDirectory()
#1 .\vendor\drush\drush\drush(4): require('C:\\Server\\data\\...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in .vendor\symfony\filesystem\Path.php on line 204

Same error wherever I do drush --version from

Comment: Drush is currently installed locally to the Drupal project. Has been installed globally previously, but I have removed it.
Using git bash I get the '[preflight] Package "drupal/core" is not installed' wherever I do drush --version from.
Thanks for your help btw

Comment: From Windows cmd: ./vendor/bin/drush --version **not** ./vendor/drush/drush. If you installed Drush globally, you need to configure in the system environmental variables.

Comment: Path to the htdocs folder\vendor\bin folder is in the environmental system variables
Run c:\..\..\htdocs\d10test\vendor\bin>drush --version
I get
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\RuntimeException: Cannot find the home directory path: Your environment or operating system isn't supported. in C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\filesystem\Path.php:204